# Install OpenSSH Server on Windows Server 2012

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, openssh

I'm trying to install and configure a windows server 2012 to run an OpenSSH server.  I'm using the Microsoft blessed version: PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH (https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases)

I was able to install and run sshd successfully. However, when I try to ssh into the server from my osx laptop I'm getting the following error:

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 10.232.37.104 port 22: Broken pipe
```

Has anyone had success with successfully installing OpenSSH server on a windows server?

I added a firewall rule and verify it is open using nmap:

```
$> sudo nmap -sS -O 10.232.37.104
Starting Nmap 7.00 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-04 14:19 EDT
Nmap scan report for 10.232.37.104
Host is up (0.023s latency).
Not shown: 988 closed ports
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp    open     ssh
```

But I am unable to successfully ssh into my server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Got to love windows...lol.  I got it working using the following steps:

```
https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/690 
You need to provide your account the following privilege "Replace a process 
level token"
secpol.msc
LocalPolicies -> User Rights Assignment
Click the policy that says "Replace a process level token" and add your 
account. Log off and log in.
```

It's so obvious, why didn't I think of that earlier!